# How can I have lnext/lprev fallback to cnext/cprev when appropriate?

Tags: vimscript, quickfix, location-list

It is often the case that I am in projects with varying filetypes. Sometimes I'm compiling using `:make<CR>` and sometimes I'm using plugins like ALE. At any given time, I probably only have one helper window (`location-list` or `quickfix`) at the bottom of my window. However, different tools choose to use either output window mapping. This annoys me, since my brain can only focus on one set of errors at a time anyway.

How can I make it so that regardless of whether I happen to have the `location-list` or `quickfix` window open, my keyboard shortcuts just "do the right thing"? I want to map `<F10>` to `:lnext` or `:cnext` and `<F9>` to `:lprev` or `:cprev`, depending on the context of the window.

Comment: Probably you may use lmake command? It is same as ":make", except the location list for the current window is used instead of the quickfix list. And then just do lnext and lprev always.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, this also applies to non-make tools, like Fzf and/or vimgrep, though, so I feel like a solution at the later stage of the pipeline might end-up working a bit more effectively and catch more scenarios/tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nnoremap <silent><F9> :call <SID>qfnext(v:false)<CR>
nnoremap <silent><F10> :call <SID>qfnext(v:true)<CR>

function! s:qfnext(next) abort
    " find all 'quickfix'-type windows on the current tab
    let qfwin = filter(getwininfo(), {_, v -> v.quickfix && v.tabnr == tabpagenr()})
    if !empty(qfwin)
        " using the first one found
        if qfwin[0].winid == getqflist({'nr': 0, 'winid': 0}).winid
            " it's quickfix
            execute a:next ? 'cnext' : 'cprev'
        else
            " assume it's loclist
            " must execute it in the host window or in loclist itself
            call win_execute(qfwin[0].winid, a:next ? 'lnext' : 'lprev', '')
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I added a fallback to lnext/lprev at the end in the case that there were no quickfix windows open, because sometimes the location-list is not visible. Thanks!

Comment: @WillBradley would you mind posting your version?

Comment: Place "execute a:next ? 'lnext' : 'lprev'" on a new line after the final endif. Note that this tends to work sometimes, but sadly not always.